# How to persist Navigation Bar across multiple UITableViews

Tags: swift, storyboard, tableview, navigationbar

I am trying to build a multi-level TableVIew display for my app, e.g.:

First TableView: List Exercise names. User can select Exercise
Second TableView: List high level exercise detail. User can select some cells to drill down

Forward and back navigation should work in a typical way, no unique routing needed.

I've hooked up the first TableView to the second TableView, and that appears to be working to navigate forward (e.g., select the exercise and see the high level detail).  However, I am not getting the Navigation bar in any view except the first TableViewController.

For the views missing it, I manually turned on the Navigation Bar in "Top Bar" from Attributes Inspector, so it now shows up in the Storyboard, but it's still missing from the Simulator.

[Code is on GitHub](https://github.com/briancl2/WorkoutTracker/tree/secondtableview/Workout%20Tracker)

[image: Storyboard]

First TableView:

[image: Working Nav Bar]

Second TableView:

[image: Missing Nav Bar]

Comment: are you using `show` segues?

Comment: What if you embed each table view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: @marosoaie yes, I am using show segues

Comment: I went through the code in your github project, but it looks like it's an older version, not the one you're posting. And the navbar looks fine: http://imgur.com/vfZJBni

Comment: @Morgan is that the right way to do this?  Conceptually I thought there was a way to push multiple ViewControllers from a single NavigationController and then pop as needed.  This would preserve the "Back" functionality while navigating forward and back through the hierarchy.  Maybe I have this wrong.

Comment: @briancl you're right, that's the correct way. One nav controller is enough

Comment: @marosoaie sorry, my bad.  I linked the wrong branch.  I fixed the link above. You found my old version prior to converting to a second TableView.  I lost the NavigationBar once I switched over to the second TableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of segue. If you open your story board, you are using a "Show Detail (e.g. Replace)" segue:
[image]

You should be using the option just before it in the list, a "Show (e.g. Push)" type segue:
[image]

Comment: When I switched from "Show Detail" to "Show" in the Attributes Inspector... it didn't work.  After I deleted the segues and re-added them as "Show," it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.
Also, another thing I noticed, you should probably present the Add New Exercise view with a "Present Modally" segue. You can then add your own Navigation Bar to the view for your Done\Cancel buttons.
It's a strange user experience to have a view "pushed" from the right, that does not have a back button.